# How to display Data from MySQL database in Node.js in browser

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to display DB data in my browser ..
my file connection.js  is

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "0000",
    database: "select_country"
});
conn.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Database is connected successfully ??????!');
});
module.exports = conn;
```

and my app.js is :

```
const http = require('http');
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;
const mysql = require('./MySql/database');

//create a server object:
const server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    mysql.query("SELECT * FROM country", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('All Countries are :-');
        res.write(result); //write a response to the client
    });

    res.write('Hello World'); //write a response to the client
    res.end(); //end the response
}); //the server object listens on port 8080

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

Error : throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event,,,,
Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end

Answer (score 1):

You must only write your responses to the client from within the callback function of `mysql.query()`.

In other words, your program runs these two lines immediately

```
res.write('Hello World'); //write a response to the client
res.end(); //end the response
```

before MySQL gets its data the callback runs. Your `res.end()` ends the output. Therefore, later, when the callback runs, it tries to `res.write()` to an already ended stream.

So move those two lines to within your callback. Try this

```
    mysql.query("SELECT * FROM country", function (err, result, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('Hello World'); //write a response to the client
        console.log('All Countries are :-');
        res.write(result); //write a response to the client
        res.end(); //end the response
    });
```

Comment: throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors.. if i do console.log(result); it's work fine .. but not working in res.write(result);